# ACCESS VBA How to add rows from multiple tables to Listbox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm making a housing Database. Multiple Villages and yearly record per Village.
Searching is through Block,Lot and Village input from user. So when the user input Village1, Block=1 and Lot=1, all of the Block 1 and Lot 1 rows from all the Village1 Tables(Village1 2019, Village1 2018, etc) will lineup in the listbox.

My current code:

```
PrevYear = Int(Year(Date) - 1)
VTblName = Me.VillageTxt & " " & PrevYear 

Do While VTblName.EOF
  PrevRecord = "SELECT * FROM ='" & VTblName & "' WHERE Block='" & Me.BlockTxt & "' AND Lot='" & Me.LotTxt & "'"

  Me.PrevRecList.RowSource = PrevRecord

  PrevYear = PrevYear - 1
Loop
```

[image]

Comment: Look up how to _normalize_ a database. You wouldn't have a table for each year, but one table only.

Comment: Per table theres a hundred records in it, 15-25 lots per block and 20-45 Block per Village, total Villages is 4. And I'm required to keep same records every year per house to see if the occupant is still the same. So how am I supposed to merged it in a table?

Comment: Additionally, I added a screenshot of my Form above, the old records supposed to lineup in the previous records listbox, and the latest will populate the textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your question but if you do not get any data than try to remove the apostrophes around the table name and the '=' sign in front of it:

```vb
  PrevRecord = "SELECT * FROM " & VTblName & " WHERE Block='" & Me.BlockTxt & "' AND Lot='" & Me.LotTxt & "'"
```

Additional if you have a space in the table name use brackets:

```vb
VTblName = "[" & Me.VillageTxt & " " & PrevYear & "]"
```

Comment: Syntax is now correct, checked it with by printing in a msgbox but listbox still doens't display anything. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide anywhere near enough information for a an actual solution but if you are trying to use SQL to combine information from 2 or more tables into one recordset/result, use `UNION`.

Having said that, the code you presented does not make much sense so either it is a small piece of a much bigger function or you have some work ahead of you towards writing code that does what you want it to do.